# Parallel EREW suffix minimum

Tags: algorithm, parallel-processing

[image]I am not sure how to approach this problem.

I have a sequence A={x1,x2....xn}

the problem is to find B:
B= {min(x1,x2....xn),min(x2....xn),(x3,x4....xn)...........min(xn-1,xn),xn}

I need to find a parallel algorithm EREW that will solve the problem in O(logn).

So far I know that it takes log(n) to find the minimum in a list of n elements with with n/2 processors. (the depth of a tree)
However because I need the algorithm to be EREW (exclusive reading and exclusive writing) each processor must read every element separately and that's why I am having a problem to solve it.. in logn..

in the picture I attached I was looking at an example of n=8.
so I have A={1,5,4,3,6,9,10,3}
I was trying to get the suffixes from the tree (in logn).. but I could get only the suffix of 
min(a7,a8}
min{a5,a6,a7,a8}
min{a1,a2,a3,a4,a5,a6,a7,a8}

Comment: A binary tree has depth log n. You can build that in EREW as well, and you can use it to find the suffix minima

Comment: I was thinking about it.. but then I can't get all the suffixes..

Comment: maybe i can attach a picture of some example..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can indeed use your binary tree to solve the problem:

**Phase 1:** Build the tree you drawed in your question. Do so layer by layer, top to bottom. All accesses are independent, so you can process a layer in O(1). You now have the range minimum written in every node.

Pseudocode:

```
for i in [0..log n]:   # layer 0 = top level in your drawing
    parallel for each node in layer i:
        node.min = min(node.left.min, node.right.min)
```

**Phase 2:** 
Process the tree from bottom to top. Write into every node the minimum of all the nodes to the right from it in the same layer. The range minima from phase 1 can be used for that.

The leafs now have all the information they need to calculate their respective suffix minimum.

Pseudocode:

```
root.right_min = infinity
for i in [log n..1]:
    parallel for each node in layer i:
        node.right.right_min = node.right_min
        node.left.right_min = min(node.right.min, node.right_min)

B = [min(node.min, node.right_min) for each node in layer 0]
```

Comment: I didn't get your algorithm... can you show me how you do it on my example tree? and also make sure two processors don't access the same leaf at the same time..

Comment: @Shiran What aspect of it? Do you know how to build the tree you drawed? because that is the first phase. If you proceed level-wise you will never have any read or write conflicts (at least I don't see how you would get those)

Comment: that's the thing... in the tree I drawed I don't get the suffix of {a6,a7,a8} for example...

Comment: @Shiran that would be phase 2 then. Proceed from bottom to top. Write into every node the minimum of all of the nodes that are sitting to the right of it in the same layer. So every node needs to store a second value along with the range minimum

Comment: do you mean that in phase two I fill the missing suffixes?

Comment: @Shiran I added some pseudocode for the second phase